# Parse a parcticular string using Boost Spirit Qi

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am new to Boost Spirit and is struggling to create a proper expression to parse the following input (actually a result of a stdout of some command):

```
^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms
```

Which I need to parse into a set of strings and integers and recorded in variables. Most of the line should be just parsed into a variable of appropriate type (string or int). So in the end, I get:

```
string:  "^+", "line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi", "+1503us", "+9103us", "55ms"
int   :   2, 7, 377, 1
```

The pair

```
+1503us[+9103us]
```

can also be with space

```
+503us[ +103us]
```

and I need stuff before square brackets and in square brackets to be placed in separate strings.

additionally, time designations can be expressed as

```
ns, ms, us, s
```

I appreciate examples about how to deal with it, because the available documentation is quite sparse and not cohesive.

---

Large piece of the log, along with headings describing the individual fields:

```
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^+ ns2.sdi.fi                    2   9   377   381  -1476us[-1688us] +/-   72ms
^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2  10   377   309   +302us[ +302us] +/-   59ms
^* heh.fi                        2  10   377   319  -1171us[-1387us] +/-   50ms
^+ stara.mulimuli.fi             3  10   377   705  -1253us[-1446us] +/-   73ms
```

Comment: Can you describe the structure of the line you've shown? Name the individual elements and define the data types they should be captured as. Are any parts optional? Are the units (us and ms) always as you've shown (us for the first two, ms for the last) or are there some variations possible?

Comment: well it is pretty obvious, but I updated the question. I  need to recognize +1503us  as string (and it can be us, ms, s, ns in all the places, so no, they are not fixed).

Comment: Yeah, some things are obvious, but better not assume :) I was also hoping to get some meaningful names for the individual entries, so I don't have to call them "element_0" - "element_8", but never mind. [Rough draft of code](http://pastebin.com/PgGyAQff) (intentionally quite verbose), I'm in process of writing an answer.

Comment: I see you found my other question. I was suppose to delete that as non-specific? @DanMašek

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **always** I start with sketching a useful AST:

```
namespace AST {
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    struct TimeSample {
        enum Direction { up, down } direction; // + or -
        clock::duration value;
    };

    struct Record {
        std::string prefix; // "^+"
        std::string fqdn;   // "line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi"
        int a, b, c, d;     // 2, 7, 377, 1
        TimeSample primary, braced;
        clock::duration tolerance;
    };
}
```

Now that we know what we want to parse, we mostly just mimick the AST with rules, for a bit:

```
using namespace qi;

start     = skip(blank) [record_];

record_   = prefix_ >> fqdn_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> sample_ >> '[' >> sample_ >> ']' >> tolerance_;

prefix_   = string("^+"); // or whatever you need to match here
fqdn_     = +graph; // or whatever additional constraints you have
sample_   = direction_ >> duration_;
duration_ = (long_ >> units_) [ _val = _1 * _2 ];
tolerance_= "+/-" >> duration_;
```

Of course, the interesting bits are the units and the direction:

```
struct directions : qi::symbols<char, AST::TimeSample::Direction> {
    directions() { add("+", AST::TimeSample::up)("-", AST::TimeSample::down); }
} direction_;
struct units : qi::symbols<char, AST::clock::duration> {
    units() {
        using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
        add("s", 1s)("ms", 1ms)("us", 1us)("µs", 1us)("ns", 1ns);
    }
} units_;
```

The white-space acceptance is governed by a skipper; I chose `qi::blank_type` for the non-lexeme rules:

```
using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
qi::rule<It, AST::Record()> start;
qi::rule<It, AST::Record(), Skipper> record_;
qi::rule<It, AST::TimeSample(), Skipper> sample_;
qi::rule<It, AST::clock::duration(), Skipper> duration_, tolerance_;
// lexemes:
qi::rule<It, std::string()> prefix_;
qi::rule<It, std::string()> fqdn_;
```

### DEMO

Putting it all together, use it:

```
int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms
)");

    std::string line;

    while (getline(iss, line)) {
        auto f = line.cbegin(), l = line.cend();
        AST::Record record;
        if (parse(f, l, parser<>{}, record))
            std::cout << "parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(record) << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "parse error\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e4f2ab25d6907ce)</kbd>**

```
parsed: (^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi 2 7 377 1 +0.001503s +0.009103s 0.055s)
```

(debug output below)

### Full Code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5e4f2ab25d6907ce)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

namespace std { namespace chrono {
    // for debug
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, duration<double> d) { return os << d.count() << "s"; }
} }

namespace AST {
    using clock = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;

    struct TimeSample {
        enum Direction { up, down } direction; // + or -
        clock::duration value;

        // for debug:
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Direction d) {
            char const* signs[] = {"+","-"};
            return os << signs[d];
        }
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, TimeSample const& sample) {
            return os << sample.direction << std::chrono::duration<double>(sample.value).count() << "s";
        }
    };

    struct Record {
        std::string prefix; // "^+"
        std::string fqdn;   // "line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi"
        int a, b, c, d;     // 2, 7, 377, 1
        TimeSample primary, braced;
        clock::duration tolerance;
    };
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::Record, prefix, fqdn, a, b, c, d, primary, braced, tolerance)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(AST::TimeSample, direction, value)

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

template <typename It = std::string::const_iterator>
struct parser : qi::grammar<It, AST::Record()> {
    parser() : parser::base_type(start) {
        using namespace qi;

        start     = skip(blank) [record_];

        record_   = prefix_ >> fqdn_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> int_ >> sample_ >> '[' >> sample_ >> ']' >> tolerance_;

        prefix_   = string("^+"); // or whatever you need to match here
        fqdn_     = +graph; // or whatever additional constraints you have
        sample_   = direction_ >> duration_;
        duration_ = (long_ >> units_) [ _val = _1 * _2 ];
        tolerance_= "+/-" >> duration_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES(
                (start)(record_)
                (prefix_)(fqdn_)(sample_)(duration_)(tolerance_)
            )
    }
  private:
    struct directions : qi::symbols<char, AST::TimeSample::Direction> {
        directions() { add("+", AST::TimeSample::up)("-", AST::TimeSample::down); }
    } direction_;
    struct units : qi::symbols<char, AST::clock::duration> {
        units() {
            using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;
            add("s", 1s)("ms", 1ms)("us", 1us)("µs", 1us)("ns", 1ns);
        }
    } units_;

    using Skipper = qi::blank_type;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Record()> start;
    qi::rule<It, AST::Record(), Skipper> record_;
    qi::rule<It, AST::TimeSample(), Skipper> sample_;
    qi::rule<It, AST::clock::duration(), Skipper> duration_, tolerance_;
    // lexemes:
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> prefix_;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()> fqdn_;
};

int main() {
    std::istringstream iss(R"(^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms
)");

    std::string line;

    while (getline(iss, line)) {
        auto f = line.cbegin(), l = line.cend();
        AST::Record record;
        if (parse(f, l, parser<>{}, record))
            std::cout << "parsed: " << boost::fusion::as_vector(record) << "\n";
        else
            std::cout << "parse error\n";

        if (f!=l)
            std::cout << "remaining unparsed input: '" << std::string(f,l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

### Debug Output

```
<start>
  <try>^+ line-17532.dyn.kp</try>
  <record_>
    <try>^+ line-17532.dyn.kp</try>
    <prefix_>
      <try>^+ line-17532.dyn.kp</try>
      <success> line-17532.dyn.kpon</success>
      <attributes>[[^, +]]</attributes>
    </prefix_>
    <fqdn_>
      <try>line-17532.dyn.kpone</try>
      <success>      2   7   377   </success>
      <attributes>[[l, i, n, e, -, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, ., d, y, n, ., k, p, o, n, e, t, ., f, i]]</attributes>
    </fqdn_>
    <sample_>
      <try>   +1503us[+9103us] </try>
      <duration_>
        <try>1503us[+9103us] +/- </try>
        <success>[+9103us] +/-   55ms</success>
        <attributes>[0.001503s]</attributes>
      </duration_>
      <success>[+9103us] +/-   55ms</success>
      <attributes>[[+, 0.001503s]]</attributes>
    </sample_>
    <sample_>
      <try>+9103us] +/-   55ms</try>
      <duration_>
        <try>9103us] +/-   55ms</try>
        <success>] +/-   55ms</success>
        <attributes>[0.009103s]</attributes>
      </duration_>
      <success>] +/-   55ms</success>
      <attributes>[[+, 0.009103s]]</attributes>
    </sample_>
    <tolerance_>
      <try> +/-   55ms</try>
      <duration_>
        <try>   55ms</try>
        <success></success>
        <attributes>[0.055s]</attributes>
      </duration_>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[0.055s]</attributes>
    </tolerance_>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[[^, +], [l, i, n, e, -, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, ., d, y, n, ., k, p, o, n, e, t, ., f, i], 2, 7, 377, 1, [+, 0.001503s], [+, 0.009103s], 0.055s]]</attributes>
  </record_>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[^, +], [l, i, n, e, -, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, ., d, y, n, ., k, p, o, n, e, t, ., f, i], 2, 7, 377, 1, [+, 0.001503s], [+, 0.009103s], 0.055s]]</attributes>
</start>
```

Comment: Ouch, I knew you were gonna beat me to it, while I was in the middle of writing it up :D Good one, as usual.

Comment: Hmm. Something wrong with Coliru. The demo live on Wandbox: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/QusDUD8SjTt6XRS3

Comment: And for good measure a Spirit X3 version: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UR3pBH9EO2FF00Q1 (I prefer the Phoenix actors in Qi...)

Answer (score 3):

Note: This answer shows a simpler approach, forming a foundation for additional techniques shown by sehe.

### Preamble

Let's enable Spirit debug output, so we can follow the progress of our parses while we're developing them.

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG 1

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
```

### Log Entry Data Structure

The first step would be to define a structure to hold out parsed log entries.

```
struct log_entry_t
{
    std::string element_0;
    std::string element_1;
    uint32_t element_2;
    uint32_t element_3;
    uint32_t element_4;
    uint32_t element_5;
    std::string element_6;
    std::string element_7;
    std::string element_8;
};
```

### Adapting the Data Structure

In order to be able to use the structure as an attribute of a Spirit grammar, we need to adapt it into a fusion tuple. (More info is in [one of Spirit tutorials](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/employee___parsing_into_structs.html)) This is achieved using [`BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html).

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    log_entry_t
    , (std::string, element_0)
    , (std::string, element_1)
    , (uint32_t, element_2)
    , (uint32_t, element_3)
    , (uint32_t, element_4)
    , (uint32_t, element_5)
    , (std::string, element_6)
    , (std::string, element_7)
    , (std::string, element_8)
)
```

### Log Line Grammar

Next, we define the grammar for the log entry. Since the individual entries may be separated by whitespace, we want to use phrase parsing, and thus need to specify a skip parser. [`qi::blank_type`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char_class.html) is an appropriate skipper, since it matches spaces and tabs only.

However, all of the elements should be treated as lexemes, we do not specify any skipper for their rules.

```
template <typename Iterator>
struct log_line_parser
    : qi::grammar<Iterator, log_entry_t(), qi::blank_type>
{
    typedef qi::blank_type skipper_t;

    log_line_parser()
        : log_line_parser::base_type(log_line)
    {
        element_0 %= qi::string("^+");
        element_1 %= qi::raw[(+qi::char_("-a-zA-Z0-9") % qi::char_('.'))];
        element_2 %= qi::uint_;
        element_3 %= qi::uint_;
        element_4 %= qi::uint_;
        element_5 %= qi::uint_;
        element_6 %= qi::raw[qi::char_('+') >> qi::uint_ >> time_unit];
        element_7 %= qi::raw[qi::char_('+') >> qi::uint_ >> time_unit];
        element_8 %= qi::raw[qi::uint_ >> time_unit];

        time_unit %= -qi::char_("nmu") >> qi::char_('s');

        log_line
            %=  element_0
            >>  element_1
            >>  element_2
            >>  element_3
            >>  element_4
            >>  element_5
            >>  element_6
            >>  qi::lit('[') >> element_7 >> qi::lit(']')
            >>  qi::lit("+/-")
            >>  element_8
            ;

        init_debug();
    }

    void init_debug()
    {
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_0);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_1);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_2);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_3);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_4);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_5);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_6);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_7);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(element_8);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(time_unit);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(log_line);
    }

private:
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> element_0;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> element_1;
    qi::rule<Iterator, uint32_t()> element_2;
    qi::rule<Iterator, uint32_t()> element_3;
    qi::rule<Iterator, uint32_t()> element_4;
    qi::rule<Iterator, uint32_t()> element_5;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> element_6;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> element_7;
    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> element_8;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()> time_unit;

    qi::rule<Iterator, log_entry_t(), skipper_t> log_line;
};
```

Let's go through some of the rules:

- Element 0 - this is a simple string we need to match. Since we wish to capture it as well, we need to use the [`string` parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/string.html).
- Element 1 - We can use the [`char_` parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/char/char.html) to match either a single character or a character set. The [`+` parser operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/plus.html) represents repetition, and the [`%` (list) parser operator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/operator/list.html) let's us parse several repetitions separated by a separator (in our case a dot).
- Element 2  - To parse numbers, we can use existing [numeric parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/numeric.html).
- Element 6 - Since we want to capture the whole sequence in a string, we use the [`raw` parser directive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/directive/raw.html)

In order to determine the resulting attribute type when using parser operators, refer to the reference of [compound attribute rules](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/quick_reference/compound_attribute_rules.html).

### Test Function

```
bool test(std::string const& log)
{
    std::cout << "Parsing: " << log << "\n\n";

    std::string::const_iterator iter(log.begin());
    std::string::const_iterator end(log.end());

    log_line_parser<std::string::const_iterator> g;

    log_entry_t entry;

    bool r(qi::phrase_parse(iter, end, g, qi::blank, entry));

    std::cout << "-------------------------\n";

    if (r && (iter == end)) {
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded\n";
        std::cout << entry.element_0 << "\n"
            << entry.element_1 << "\n"
            << entry.element_2 << "\n"
            << entry.element_3 << "\n"
            << entry.element_4 << "\n"
            << entry.element_5 << "\n"
            << entry.element_6 << "\n"
            << entry.element_7 << "\n"
            << entry.element_8 << "\n";
    } else {
        std::string::const_iterator some = iter + 30;
        std::string context(iter, (some > end) ? end : some);
        std::cout << "Parsing failed\n";
        std::cout << "stopped at: \": " << context << "...\"\n";
    }

    return r;
}
```

### Main Function

Finally, let's run a few positive and negative tests on our parser.

```
int main()
{
    bool result(true);
    result &= test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[ +9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503ms[+9103ns] +/-   55s");

    result &= !test("^- line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= !test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55 ms");
    result &= !test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   + 1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= !test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   +377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= !test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   3 77     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");
    result &= !test("^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   -377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms");


    std::cout << "Test result = " << result << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

After a lot of debugging output (example for the first test):

```
Parsing: ^+ line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi      2   7   377     1   +1503us[+9103us] +/-   55ms

<log_line>
  <try>^+ line-17532.dyn.kp</try>
  <element_0>
    <try>^+ line-17532.dyn.kp</try>
    <success> line-17532.dyn.kpon</success>
    <attributes>[[^, +]]</attributes>
  </element_0>
  <element_1>
    <try>line-17532.dyn.kpone</try>
    <success>      2   7   377   </success>
    <attributes>[[l, i, n, e, -, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, ., d, y, n, ., k, p, o, n, e, t, ., f, i]]</attributes>
  </element_1>
  <element_2>
    <try>2   7   377     1   </try>
    <success>   7   377     1   +</success>
    <attributes>[2]</attributes>
  </element_2>
  <element_3>
    <try>7   377     1   +150</try>
    <success>   377     1   +1503</success>
    <attributes>[7]</attributes>
  </element_3>
  <element_4>
    <try>377     1   +1503us[</try>
    <success>     1   +1503us[+91</success>
    <attributes>[377]</attributes>
  </element_4>
  <element_5>
    <try>1   +1503us[+9103us]</try>
    <success>   +1503us[+9103us] </success>
    <attributes>[1]</attributes>
  </element_5>
  <element_6>
    <try>+1503us[+9103us] +/-</try>
    <time_unit>
      <try>us[+9103us] +/-   55</try>
      <success>[+9103us] +/-   55ms</success>
      <attributes>[[u, s]]</attributes>
    </time_unit>
    <success>[+9103us] +/-   55ms</success>
    <attributes>[[+, 1, 5, 0, 3, u, s]]</attributes>
  </element_6>
  <element_7>
    <try>+9103us] +/-   55ms</try>
    <time_unit>
      <try>us] +/-   55ms</try>
      <success>] +/-   55ms</success>
      <attributes>[[u, s]]</attributes>
    </time_unit>
    <success>] +/-   55ms</success>
    <attributes>[[+, 9, 1, 0, 3, u, s]]</attributes>
  </element_7>
  <element_8>
    <try>55ms</try>
    <time_unit>
      <try>ms</try>
      <success></success>
      <attributes>[[m, s]]</attributes>
    </time_unit>
    <success></success>
    <attributes>[[5, 5, m, s]]</attributes>
  </element_8>
  <success></success>
  <attributes>[[[^, +], [l, i, n, e, -, 1, 7, 5, 3, 2, ., d, y, n, ., k, p, o, n, e, t, ., f, i], 2, 7, 377, 1, [+, 1, 5, 0, 3, u, s], [+, 9, 1, 0, 3, u, s], [5, 5, m, s]]]</attributes>
</log_line>
-------------------------
Parsing succeeded
^+
line-17532.dyn.kponet.fi
2
7
377
1
+1503us
+9103us
55ms
```

the program prints the following line:

```
Test result = 1
```

---

[Live sample on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6c3a925abbfa975)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those times I can almost feel some sympathy for people who claim that C++ has just added complexity, and C was really better. It does lose some things like type safety, but consider what reading this looks like with C's `scanf`:

```
struct record {
    char prefix[256];
    char url[256];
    int a, b, c, d;
    char time1[256];
    char time2[256];
    char time3[256];
};

sscanf(input, 
       "%255s %255s %d %d %d %d %255[^[][ %255[^]]] +/- %255s",
       r.prefix, r.url, &r.a, &r.b, &r.c, &r.d, r.time1, r.time2, r.time3);
```

This does, of course, have a few potential liabilities:

1. It reads into arrays of char instead of `std::string`s.
2. `scanf` and cousins aren't type safe.
3. It doesn't try to verify the suffixes on the times.
4. A Spirit-based parser may easily be at least somewhat faster.

If any of these is really a serious problem for your purposes, you might really need a different approach. Given what it *looks* like the code is probably intended to do, it's not immediately obvious that any of them is likely to cause a real problem though.

Comment: Not bad for some tasks :) I always assume people will want to _use_ the parsed information, which really only is comfortable for the ints there, IMO. But yeah, it sure has some elegance.

Comment: @sehe: It still produces NUL-terminated byte sequences, so if (for example) you really need `std::string` in the output, it's pretty trivial to construct those (though doing so obviously adds more code).

Comment: Yeah. I  was referring mostly to the measurement values

Comment: @sehe: Oh--I left those as strings only because that's what he asked for in the question.Would be pretty trivial to read those as numbers as well, if we wanted to.